# Instrumental of manner in Russian?

Tags: творительный-падеж, ukrainian

Recently I stumbled accross a definition of how to use the Instrumental in Russian. It is very detailed and lays out very many different possibilities in a systematic way. It talks about the "Instrumental of means", "Instrumental of adjunction", etc. etc. but it never mentions a so called "Instrumental of manner", which I found later in a book about Ukrainian grammar.

An example from the book about Ukrainian would be:

> говорити ніжним голосом

meaning "to speak in a soft voice."

Now I wonder if this can also be done with the Instrumental case in Russian or if this is specific to Ukrainian.

PS: I do not speak a word of Russian or Ukrainian, my interest comes from a purely linguistic perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can, this function of Instrumental is characteristic of both languages.

In Russian

> говорить нежным голосом